# using sql in operator by Linq

Tags: linq-to-entities

how can I simulate the following sql query using linq

```
Select * From Resource Where Id in
(
Select ResourceId From ResourceRelCategory Where CategoryId =8 
)
```

note that Resource and Category have Many to Many relationship and ResourceRelCategory is an association table between them.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
var result = from r in Resource
             where (
                 select c from ResourceRelCategory
                 where c.CategoryId==8
                 select c.ResourceId
             ).Contains(r.Id)
             select r;
```

or

```
var result = from r in Resource
             where r.Categories.Any(c => c.Id == 8)
             select r;
```

or maybee the other way around:

```
Category.First(c => c.Id == 8).Resources
```

Comment: the problem is the ResourceRelCategory isn't in mapping files becuase it is just an association entity. there are just Resource and Category entities in Model.

Comment: @Vahid: Why don't just add them? If you use automtic generation you can add a "dummy column" so the relation table gets a mapping.

Comment: i guess the associatoin table should not be in class model. what do you think?

Comment: Mr chfrin, could you help me what do i do if i have a list of dynamic generated category ids when the number of thoes is not specific in desing time.

Comment: @Vahid: Try something like `where r.Categories.Exists(c => catIds.Contains(c.Id))`

Answer (score 0):

See the article about this here
I have already posted about the same at 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/336253/Filtering-records-from-List-based-similar-to-Sql-I